# com.mangofactory.swagger.ScalaUtils Class unable to figure the dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, swagger

In our project we are working on the POM cleanup activities and upgrading the jar versions to the extent possible, for swagger web mvc the dependency we used was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

However since version 0.9.4 the package com.mangofactory.swagger which had the class ScalaUtils.java has been removed, i am running out of clue as to how to find this utility class elsewhere.
I am upgrading this since i have to upgrade to a better spring version which isnt supported but 0.8.8 version of above.

Any help or guidance sincerely appriciated.

Comment: Why do you need the class? As of 0.9.5 we removed Scala support so that class is no longer required. Since you're on the upgrade path I would recommend upgrading to 2.2.2.

Comment: Actually some of the existing code of the application is using the methods toOption and scala converters and hence i am in a bit of fix

Comment: U can copy the Scala util class from an earlier release. GitHub should have that class if u look at the tagged version in the repo

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand your question. You think swagger-springmvc version 0.9.1 is missing ScalaUtils, but I just checked online and swagger-springmvc still has ScalaUtils.java. May be your donwloading a wrong file

Please check the links below: (especialy the 1st one)

[Link number 1](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc/0.9.1/)

AND

[Link number 2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc/0.9.1/com/mangofactory/swagger/ScalaUtils.java)

I hope it will get you on a right path.

Comment: My apologies it was 0.9.4 and not 0.9.1